# How to center ui-float-label

Tags: css, primeng

I'm having the following template:

```
<div class="smallCard">
    <p-card class="centered">
        <p-header>
            <img width="200" height="100" src="assets/images/vendor.svg" />
        </p-header>

        <p-messages></p-messages>

        <span class="ui-float-label">
            <input id="username" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="username" required>
            <label for="username">{{'Username' | translate}}</label>
        </span>

        <br>

        <span class="ui-float-label">
            <input id="password" type="password" pPassword [feedback]="false" [(ngModel)]="password" required />
            <label for="password">{{'Password' | translate}}</label>
        </span>

        <br>

        <p-checkbox name="permanent" value="true" label="{{'Remember me' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="isPermanent">
        </p-checkbox>

        <p-footer>
            <p-button label="Login" (onClick)="login()"></p-button>
        </p-footer>

    </p-card>
</div>
```

Where as the important css classes are:

```
.centered
{
    text-align: center;
}

.smallCard
{
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 40%;
}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Obviously the labels aren't centered / aligned with the inputs. But how do I achieve this with primeng's float labels?

Comment: would you being willing to create a stackblitz?

Comment: I'll try when I return to work tomorrow. Never done that before

Answer (score 0):

The label should have an absolute position;

For example:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("label");

function handleFocus() {
  element.classList.add("active");
}

function handleBlur() {
  var myInput = document.getElementById("input");
  if (!myInput.value) {
      element.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  left: 10px;
}

.active {
  height: 20px;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  widt: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <label id='label'>blabla</label>
  <input id='input'
        onFocus="handleFocus();"
        onBlur="handleBlur();"
  />
</div>
```